# Xcode 5 Link lrypto

Tags: c, xcode, linker, xcode5

I am trying to compile [keychaindump](https://github.com/juuso/keychaindump) in Xcode 5 and I know that it requires the `-lcrypto` flag. How can I include the library in the project? I noticed some other similar questions but I think the options have changed in Xcode 5.